# multiple queries regarding Oracle Views and Grants

Tags: oracle

Multiple questions - so please excuse if the post gets long

have a read only access to an Oracle  schema where I can see certain views
Say views '**X**' and '**Y**'

now need to create a View on top of these 2 views
1 >Not sure if from performance perspective this is a good idea ?
( the new view will be used for firing selects only )

The two existing views '**X**' and '**Y**' are themselves created **off** some other views '**A**' and '**B**' !!

The weird thing is I can fire a query like :

```
select * from <<schema_name>>.X
```

2 >However I cannot access the view **A** or **B** directly - so do I need to have grants to **A** and **B**  ?

when I look at the DDL statement for View X and View Y I see the following code :

```
create view <<schema_name>>.X as 
select emp_first_name,emp_last_name,  
from <<schema_name>>.A
```

However when I fire a query like this :

```
select * from <<schema_name>>.X -
```

I get results like :

```
  first_name,last_name
```

3 >Confused about why the results show field names like `first_name,last_name` when the view has it defined as `emp_first_name` and `emp_last_name` ?

Comment: When you have three questions you should create three separate posts. The question title does not really relate to your questions.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. `sqldeveloper freeware alternative` is not only nothing related to your question, it's not a question and has no meaning. (Looking for a freeware alternative to SQLDeveloper would be off-topic here, as it's a Google or Bing search topic and not an SO question.) This should also be posted as multiple separate questions; you can always link back to the first one for the others for some context.

Comment: thanks for letting me know - I wanted to ask about sql developer but the forum specified it did not meet the quality standards - so I updated it with my other question but had forgotten to update the title ! - thanks

Comment: How did you get your DDL? try this query: `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'X', '<<schema_name>>') from dual`

Comment: Used sql developer to get the ddl of the 'X' view thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1> Views on Views might cause some performance issues, deppends mostly on the inner views.
Read more in [this AskTom post](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:9087996409290)

2> This is not wierd - that's what views do, instead of letting you select the whole table, they let you select only part of it. So you need grants on A and B.

3> Strange, Try this query and see how it was really created-

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW', 'X', '<<schema_name>>') 
  from dual
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs on #1 & #2 - tried what you have suggested for #3 in sql developer - says the object does not exist - so again could this be a grant issue ?

Comment: @satishmarathe, you probably don't have privileges for dbms_metadata. If you connect via sqlplus and execute the command `desc <<schema_name>>.X` what do you see ? BTW, don't you have a DBA that can execute this query ?

Comment: thanks ! - I completely forgot the desc command - it shows me the fields as they are seen in the select  - the funny thing is - both SQL Developer extracted DDL and also 'all_views' are still giving me the wrong ddl - but thanks for helping out!